# Javasript code won't work in Safari 8/9 versions

Tags: javascript

js duplicate input script won't work in Safari 8/9 only (maybe some more), all version higher is ok including Edge/Mozila/Chrome. Can't find problem.

```
<script>
  document.getElementById("one").oninput = () => {
  const input = document.getElementById('one');
  const output = document.getElementById('two');
  output.value = input.value;
};</script>
```

Comment: Try replacing `() => {}` with `function() {}` and `const` with `var`. Those won't work in IE 11 and other old browsers

Comment: Arrow functions weren't added until Safari 10. Use traditional functions.

Answer (score 0):

Arrow functions aren't supported in many older browsers so you'll need to replace it with a function expression.

```
<script>
  document.getElementById("one").oninput = function() {
    var input = document.getElementById('one');
    var output = document.getElementById('two');
    output.value = input.value;
  };
</script>
```